# 18.04 Gnome-Wayland Screensaver ignores configuration?

Tags: xorg, wayland, gnome-screensaver

I have setup the screensaver for normal X11-Gnome to never lock the screen, log me out, dim, etc. This is my HTPC.

I am trying to experiment with Wayland, but no matter how hard I try I am logged off after a few minutes of inactivity. Is it possible that the configuration values are coming from a different place than for X11-Gnome? I have checked screensaver settings using gsettings, Settings gui, dconf, tweaks and even Compiz.

Here is the config:

```
$ gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.desktop.screensaver
org.gnome.desktop.screensaver picture-opacity 100
org.gnome.desktop.screensaver logout-enabled false
org.gnome.desktop.screensaver lock-enabled false
org.gnome.desktop.screensaver logout-delay uint32 0
org.gnome.desktop.screensaver embedded-keyboard-enabled false
org.gnome.desktop.screensaver primary-color '#023c88'
org.gnome.desktop.screensaver idle-activation-enabled false
org.gnome.desktop.screensaver secondary-color '#5789ca'
org.gnome.desktop.screensaver logout-command ''
org.gnome.desktop.screensaver color-shading-type 'solid'
org.gnome.desktop.screensaver embedded-keyboard-command ''
org.gnome.desktop.screensaver show-notifications false
org.gnome.desktop.screensaver picture-options 'zoom'
org.gnome.desktop.screensaver lock-delay uint32 0
org.gnome.desktop.screensaver show-full-name-in-top-bar true
org.gnome.desktop.screensaver picture-uri 'file:///usr/share/backgrounds/warty-final-ubuntu.png'
org.gnome.desktop.screensaver status-message-enabled true
org.gnome.desktop.screensaver ubuntu-lock-on-suspend false
org.gnome.desktop.screensaver user-switch-enabled true
```

My system is i5-4690K, Haswell graphics

Answer (score 1):

Problem does NOT appear to be due to screensaver, rather it occurs when running Kodi in Wayland AND turning your display off. When you do this, gnome-shell segfaults. You may need to leave display off a minute or two before the problem shows up.

Bug: #1789962 opened: gnome-shell segfaults in Wayland when display is turned off while Kodi running.